# Specify Generic type and interface

Tags: c#

I need to have a list where all items extend class A and implement interface I. Additionally class A might be multiple parents up in the hierarchy.

If all the classes were direct descendants of class A I could just use an Abstract class that implements I as the generic and use that, but my use case doesn't allow for this.

is there a way to tell a List that its elements must both extend class A and implement interface I ? `List<A,I>` ? If not is there another way around this?

Example Code:

```
public class A
{
    // Class belongs to a third party library
}

public class B : A
{
    // Class belongs to a third party library
    public string Text{ get; set; }
}

public class C : A
{
    // Class belongs to a third party library
    public string Other{ get; set; }
}

interface I
{
    // Belongs to me
    bool shouldSend();
    string getName();
    string getValue();
}

public class MyClass : B, I 
{
      public string Name{ get; set; }

      public function myClass(ObjectWithName obj)
      {
           Name = obj.Name;
      }

      public string getValue()
      {
          return Text;
      }

      public bool shouldSend()
      {
          return true;
      }
}

public class MyClass2 : C, I 
{
      public string Name{ get; set; }

      public function myClass(ObjectWithName obj)
      {
           Name = obj.Name;
      }

      public string getValue()
      {
          return Other;
      }

      public bool shouldSend()
      {
          return true;
      }
}

public class mainActions
{
    // Here is where I need the list to use both restrictions
    public List<A,I> myList;
    // The class I need to use these things in
    public function mainActions(List<ObjectWithName> elements)
    {
        ThirdPartyCollection TPC = new ThirdPartyCollection();
        foreach(var el in elements)
        {
            MyList.Add(new MyClass(el));
            MyList.Add(new MyClass2(el));
            // TPC.Add accepts implementations of A here
            TPC.Add(MyList.ElementAt(MyList.Count - 1));
            TPC.Add(MyList.ElementAt(MyList.Count - 2));
        }


    }

    public function doThisLater()
    {
        foreach(var el in myList)
        {
            if(el.shouldSend())
            {
                // I need an implementation of I here
                doSomethingElse(el.getName(), el.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** For anyone coming in search of an answer here in the future, it doesn't seem to be possible. Instead I used @servys answer and made a new list to hold my sub class objects:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T> where T : A, I
{
}
```

Then I kept different lists for each subclass:

```
protected MyList<MyClass> MCList = new MyList<MyClass>();
protected MyList<MyClass2> MCList2 = new MyList<MyClass2>();
```

Comment: It would probably help clarify your question to put some example code, psuedo code will suffice if its all you can do but since this is tagged as C# you may want to use as much syntax as possible.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that now.

Comment: Say that B, C, and D inherit A, and B and D implement I. Would B and D need to be eligible to be in the same list?

Comment: Added code to clarify my use case.

Comment: You could maintain two lists, one of `A` and one of `I`, and have an `.Add<T>()` that constrains its type to `A` and `I` that adds the item to both lists. Of course the same thing can be done with just one list and casting back and forth, saving memory while being uglier -- but it does suggest a possible point for splitting the class.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram yes. They both need to be in the list. If that's possible.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for the suggestion. I hadn't thought of that. I might have to go that route if there is no other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify generic constraints you can specify as many as you want, and *all* of them must be met, so you can simply add a generic constraint of `A` and `I` to your type, and a type has to meet both of those constraints to be a valid generic argument.

```
public class ClassThatNeedsABetterName<T> : List<T>
    where T : A, I
{ }
```

Comment: I suspect OP wants a list that will accept mixed instances of any class that inherits `A` and implements `I`. This solution allows one class (and its subclasses, ofc) that meets the requirements per list.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: which is just as well, because the fully general case isn't possible in C#'s type model. Not statically, at least, without introducing an interface that both `A` and `I` implement.

Comment: I'm after what @Blorgbeard mentions. Thank you.

Comment: I'm very new to C#. I don't fully understand what the class is meant to do. Could you give it a better name or explain its purpose in this case? Thanks.

Comment: @Bryan It's a list of items of a type that extends (through any number of layers of indirection) `A` and that implement the interface `I`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but I'm only able to use it like ClassThatNeedsABetterName<MyClass> but the list needs to have MyClass and MyClass2, both of which extend A and implement I.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like `public class ClassThatNeedsABetterName<T> : List<T>
    where T : I
{ }` then use it like `ClassThatNeedsABetterName<A>`  ?

Comment: @Bryan You could only do that if `A` implements `I`.  If it does, you don't need a new class at all, just use a `List<A>`.  If it doesn't, then you can't do that.

Comment: This didn't exactly do what I want, but it doesn't seem like that's possible. Using your idea here, I am able to keep a list for each subclass of A that can be used where A or I are required, so this gets me to a usable work around. Thanks.